# Spring Boot Java 6 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: X : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to put a app built on top of Spring Boot to run in an environment with Java 6, I'm finding some problems. I did some testing, I downloaded a new project by start.spring.io set to Java 6 and the problem still persists.

I'm finding it strange because the project recovered by start.spring.io (set to Java 6) does not apply the recommended settings [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6) to run on Java 6

After applying the recommended settings described on the site, the error persists.

With Jetty settings:

```
ERROR 7776 --- [main] osboot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org / apache / tomcat / jdbc / pool / DataSource: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

With Tomcat configurations:

```
 05/14/2015 07: 50: 18,112 ERROR 10852 --- [main]
 osboot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
 javax / annotation / ManagedBean: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

JDK version:
1.6.0_45

Spring Boot:
v1.2.3.RELEASE

Build with Gradle

Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The thumb rule is that code must be run on a JRE which is higher than the one used at compile time.
Here code was compiled on JDK 7 (.minor version 51.0) and is being run on JRE 6. Hence, the error.

Comment: Java 6 has been end-of-public-updates since February 2013, ask yourself if you really want to run on such an outdated version.

Comment: I am aware of the reasons for the error "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 ', which I'm not understanding is why the Spring Boot not run on Java 6 because in the own documentation has a section for settings that environment.

Also, unfortunately, it is now necessary (: ~) run the system in java 6

Comment: Use tomcat7 instead of tomcat8. By default spring boot uses this which requires  a minimum of Java7 and not Java6. This version also contains a Tomcat JDBC version compiled with Java7 and will therefor not run on Java6. To switch tomcat versions read [this section of the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-7).

Comment: add `<properties>
 <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>` to your pom.xml

Comment: thanks @MichałMaciejGałuszka this worked for java 6. Now spring boot server started with addition of this property in pom.xml

Comment: @LucasOliveira  I'm using gradle, I did set the tomcat version to tomcat7 instead of tomcat8, but still getting the same error. How did you fix this?

Comment: @PKR I have updated the Java version from 6 to 8... nowadays new versions of many libraries are only compatible from Java 7+ :(. In my case, it was possible... good luck.

Answer (score 4):

The tomcat jdbc-pool is compiled with Java 7 (version 51.0) and therefore incompatible with Java 6.