# Will a jar compiled with java 1.6.0_45 run in java 1.6.0 environment?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar compiled with java 1.6.0_45 but when I try to run this on an AIX machine having java 1.6.0 it gives me the below exception:

```
2016-08-12 15:32:39,179 WARN o.s.b.SpringApplication [main] Error handling failed (no error message)
2016-08-12 15:32:39,197 INFO o.h.v.i.u.Version [background-preinit] HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
2016-08-12 15:32:39,249 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication [main] Application startup failed
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=javax/annotation/ManagedBean, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:529) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:440) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:68) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1027) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:89) ~[DiamondFeedGeneratorCMTTool-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.registerDefaultFilters(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.<init>(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:111) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1345) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:77) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:595) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.td.diamond.cmt.feed.generator.config.DiamondFeedGeneratorConfig.main(DiamondFeedGeneratorConfig.java:44) [classes!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600) ~[?:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [DiamondFeedGeneratorCMTTool-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [DiamondFeedGeneratorCMTTool-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [DiamondFeedGeneratorCMTTool-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [DiamondFeedGeneratorCMTTool-1.0.jar:?]
```

Any suggestions what the issue could be and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you by any chance packaging java ee api jar ?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: @Nicolas It's a spring boot web application.

Comment: @Youcef Yes I have. But what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: What web container / app server do you use?

Comment: @Stefan - As this is a Spring boot application so it runs on the bundled tomcat and the tomcat version that I have configured is 7.0.59

Comment: @Vineet Ah, ok. I figured it could be Tomcat 8. Then this would have been relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235671/spring-boot-java-6-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-x-unsupported-major

Comment: @Stefan I already have this configuration in my pom to use tomcat 7.0.59 and not Tomcat 8.

Comment: @Vineet I understand. Where does the `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` class come from (which jar)? As I read the stacktrace ManagedBean must have been compiled with Java 7 or higher.

Comment: @Vineet The javax.annotation.Ma‌​nagedBean from `tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar` has been compiled for target 1.6. I'd check that you don't have a second incarnation of j.a.Ma‌​nagedBean on the classpath that was compiled for target > 1.6.

Comment: I couldn't find any other instance of j.a.Ma‌​nagedBean on the classpath. I am going to upgrade the java version to 1.6.0_45 and will check if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @Vineet You could try a `Class.forName("javax.annotation.Ma‌​nagedBean")` with your 1.6.0 first. I'd be really baffled if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a spring boot application but in your classpath (lib directory of your war for example) a Java EE API jar is present ([javaee-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) or [servlet-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api)). It does not contain the implementation of the annotation ManagedBean and thus it throws the error.

Usually, this type of library is used for compilation only in an application deployed on server implementing these specifications (Servlet or Java EE).

Comment: You might want to provide further clarification that he has included stub 'for compilation only' versions of those libraries, which cannot work at runtime.